# Most efficient way to store and retrieve large amounts of text data in android

Tags: android, data-storage

I wanna write an android application which will store and retrieve large amounts of text data. I wanna store text in paragraph wise.I need to manipulate this text data in an efficient way. What will be the best way for doing this?

Comment: please consider to accept answer if your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to save all data inside a file. And save this file to specified location in sdcard. If you are saving data inside a file you will get same format as you saved(e.g Paragraph wise in your case).And you can delete file when ever you want.

I found this may this help you to solve your issue

**SharedPreferences** is apparently implemented internally as an XML file which is serialized and deserialized in full on update. And it's a Key-Value store with no index. So use that only for simple data associated with your app. Any more than 50 keys and you've probably overdone it.

**ContentProvider** is intended for sharing data across applications. You've explicitly said you don't want to do that.

**SQLiteDatabase** is intended for individual apps to store data, and provides a lot of flexibility to store and index data in different ways. I personally use it to store logs in one of my apps. I'd recommend that route.

[See this discussion for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617307/best-way-to-store-data-in-android)